# Unable to Access mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have mysqldump under Program Files/MySQL/MySQL 5.6/bin but I cannot access on the command line. I even tried inserting the entire file directory but it did not work. I know typing in mysqldump should work on the command line. What seems to be problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not in your `PATH` so you should adjust that.

If specifying the full path to the executable does not work, then maybe you're mistaken on its location, or you need to post the error message you get.